# PyCharm: How to switch to regular HTML comments (Ctrl+Slash) in Django

Tags: django, pycharm

My PyCharm is using Django template-style comments {# #} when editing HTML files. Is there any way to change it to regular HTML comments? I don't use Django templates, and I'm tired of typing comments by hand.

Comment: side note, you have comments not exposed to clients, why do you prefer standard html ones?

Comment: I think django templates were turned off somehow in my project, so HTML comments were the only option

Answer (score 42, accepted):

File | Settings | Python Template Languages, change "Template language" to None.

Comment: but won't this show errors to all django templates written? (e.g. {% extends 'base.html' %} )

Answer (score 5):

If you come across this and have a later version of Pycharm, you can find the setting by opening `PyCharm | Preferences` or `⌘,`. Then `Languages & Frameworks | Python Template Languages`. There you can set the Template language to None for HTML Template file types.

[image]